# Error while trying to run a node process on AWS ubuntu Server using pm2

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, server, pm2

I am trying to run a node process on an AWS Ubuntu server and I keep getting this error.

`[PM2][ERROR] Script not found: /home/user/app-name/“npm`

Here is the command I am running
`pm2 start “npm run start” --name app-name`

I have tried to use `yarn` as well and I am getting similar error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed the double quotes you used in the command has been formatted, you must have copied and pasted the command into an application like slack, I ran into similar issue a while ago.

Do this:
Use actual double quotes `"`

Run this:
`pm2 start "npm run start" --name app-name`

Answer (score 2):

It should be `"` and not `“`.

<sub>And the morale of the story is: Don't abuse a word processor as code editor! This is what happens when you type code into Microsoft Word or similar applications. They are meant for writing, not for coding.</sub>